# How to cast media to default media receiver of the Chromecast device?

Tags: android, chromecast

Trying to cast media to default media receiver of the Chromecast from android app, but it doesn't cast at all. Following is the code snippet using to find the routes :

```
MediaRouteSelector selector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
    .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent
    .categoryForRemotePlayback(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID))
    .build();
```

Then, it will show the Chromecast device within the WiFi and running the following code when the device is selected :

```
MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = adapter.getItem(position).routeInfo;
// select the route for usage
route.select();
// send the play control request with the video uri
route.sendControlRequest(
    new Intent(MediaControlIntent.ACTION_PLAY)
    .setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/mp4")
    .addCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK),
    new MediaRouter.ControlRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(String error, Bundle data) {
            super.onError(error, data);
        }
        @Override
        public void onResult(Bundle data) {
            super.onResult(data);
        }
    }
);
```

It can't cast the media to the device. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not using the Cast SDK but using the Media Route Provider. I don't see any session being set up; you might want to look at the democastplayer sample code that is distributed along with the Android SDK (under SDK folder, go to extras/google/google_play_service/samples/cast/democastplayer). In that sample, look at the MrpCastPlayerActivity class.

Comment: Is it possible to stream local media to Chromecast device without using local Http OR cloud servers ?